# Socketcan interface stops responding when there's no WiFi

Tags: networking, wifi, can-bus, wpa-supplicant

Starting the can0 interface using command:

`ip link set can0 type can bitrate 250000 restart-ms 100` in /etc/rc.local

This works perfectly whenever the pi zero connects to a recognized WiFi network.

However when the pi zero boots with no recognized WiFi networks nearby the socketcan device (canable running candle) no longer registers any CAN messages  60s from boot. The CAN device works perfectly up to that ~60s point. The can0 interface still shows up under `ifconfig` but it can no longer see the attached CAN network (on top of this the blue led light no longer turns on when it normally blinks whenever it detects a new message after proper init.)). Only a reboot seems to fix the CAN interface.

Already tried adding `denyinterfaces can0` to dhcpcd.conf

Example scenarios:

1. Pi boots with no wifi -> 60s later loses CAN communication
2. Pi boots with wifi -> more than 10min later still holds CAN communication
3. Pi boots with wifi -> 5 mins later drops wifi connection -> 60s later
   loses CAN communication

Comment: if the wifi connection is (re-)established once CAN is lost, is CAN re-established too?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: What operating system do you use? Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: Running the latest version of buster lite. Even removing code from rc.local and init socketcan using hotplug in network/interfaces causes the same issue